# How to apply button style on runtime in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

How to apply runtime button style in android kotlin?

**My Style (themes.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="WhiteButtonLightTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorGray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RedButtonLightTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorRed</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorGray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GreenButtonLightTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGreen</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorGray</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**My Kotlin Code:**

```
var btnOpt4 = Button(con)
btnOpt4 = rv.findViewById(R.id.btnOption4) as Button
```

Comment: Please post activity class. can you apply theme to whole activity

Answer (score 3):

You can directly call by id to button
 `( by using apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions')`

in your activity and set style by this:

```
 button.setTextAppearance(R.style.AlertDialog_AppCompat)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this might answer the question, consider supporting your answer with references and links on why/how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**use below code**

```
btn.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium);
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always benefit from the addition of some explanation. In this case explain why you think this will fix the problem and where this code should be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnOpt4 = rv.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOption4)
btnOpt4.setTextAppearance(R.style.RedButtonLightTheme)
```

also you can use `setBackgroundResource` method to change background style of button in runtime:

```
btnOpt4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_drawable)
```